# admin panel in Django creating for to change Product media and text from webpage

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-templates

I have created a website in Django that contains product details and captions.

Now, I want to create a dynamic admin panel that performs the following tasks without using code (because the client has no idea about coding):

1. Add or change product photos and details.
2. change or add any paragraphs or details on the website.

( just like we are changing the our images on social media account without using any coding like using prebuilded system)

So here is what to do as the next step in processing this: pls guide me

i have tried models but i don't understand it very well

Comment: so you want your client to be able to edit, Create, and delete Products and their values in the easiest way, right ?

Comment: there is already a django admin panel. you need to access the admin panel by typing https://yourdomain_name.com/admin

Comment: or http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this propose you can use this examples

Profile picture: add a new field with profile name and field type Image to your User model or Profile model and admin can easily add profile

for dynamic content on frontend: create a model Content and add a field Text with  RichTextField Field from ckEditor module that crested for this propose

all of them is a minimum example and show you how we can hide details of code under abstract things

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/

Steps to follow are:-
1.creating superuser for project .
2. register model as admin in admin.py for that app.
3. now the model can be seen in {url}/admin/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).